# Placeholder doesn`t show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made some jquery validation and I want some text to appear as `placeholder` when user went out of `input` and didn't write something.

I wrote this code

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function() {
    if ( !!$(this).val() ) {
        $(this).css({
            'border': '#ff8383 1px solid'
        });
        $(this).attr('placeholder', 'this field is required');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({
            'border': '#c3c3c3 1px solid'
        });
        $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
    }
});
```

It works in chrome dev tool
[chrome dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vslSt.jpg), but it doesn`t show up on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an extra `!` here:

```
 !!$(this).val()
```

and you can join `css` with `attr` in same `(this)`

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function() {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).css({
      'border': '#ff8383 1px solid'
    }).attr('placeholder', 'this field is required');
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      'border': '#c3c3c3 1px solid'
    }).attr('placeholder', '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="" />
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: At first i wrote single "!", but if statement did not work. That`s because i had value=" " in my html. You gave me a clue.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the issue; you have 2 bangs in the if statement.

```
 if ( !!$(this).val() ) {
```